# JSON schema : how to have arrays with the same artitrary nb of elements

Tags: arrays, json, schema

I have JSON files with several arrays looking like (here 3 elements in the example, but it can change depending on the described object).

```
  {
      "SENSOR_MOUNT"      : ["MOUNTED_ON_GLIDER","MOUNTED_ON_GLIDER","MOUNTED_ON_GLIDER"],
      "SENSOR_ORIENTATION": ["DOWNWARD","DOWNWARD","DOWNWARD"],
      "PARAMETER"             : ["CHLA", "BBP700","CDOM"],
      "PARAMETER_SENSOR"      : ["FLUOROMETER_CHLA", "BACKSCATTERINGMETER_BBP700", "FLUOROMETER_CDOM"],
      "PARAMETER_DATA_MODE"   : ["R","R","R"]
  }
```

Is there a way to control with the associated schema that the vectors in the JSON have the same **arbitrary** number of elements ?

Comment: Not possible with JSONSchema.